# ubuntu 12.40 get mouse position from SSH

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, xdotool

i need to obtain the position (x,y) of pointer, but i need this from external connection (SSH).
In desktop, works with this:

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

But when i run the command from SSH (remote), giveme the error:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable X11 forwarding using the `ssh -X` flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xdotool getmouselocation
```

Just export display